# Prove or disprove a Hölder type bound on antiderivative

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

Let $f:(0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R_{\ge0}$ be a continuous function such that for every $t_0\in [0,1]$,
$$\int_0^{t_0} [f(t)-f(t_0)]\,dt\le c_1 t_0^\gamma$$
for $0<\gamma<1$ and $c_1>0$. Does it follow that
$$\int_0^{t_0} f(t)dt\le c_2t_0^\gamma$$
for some $c_2>0$?

I know that this fails to hold if for example $\gamma=1$ we can have $f(t)=-\log t$ but I have no idea how to prove this for $0<\gamma<1$.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g(t)=\int_0^{t} f(\tau)d\tau$. Then
$$g(t)+g'(t)t\le c_1 t^\gamma$$
i.e.
$$\bigg(\frac{g(t)}{t}\bigg)'=\frac{g(t)+g'(t)t}{t^2}\le \frac{c_1}{t^{2-\gamma}}.$$
Integrating over $t\in [t_0,1]$,
$$g(t_0)\le ct_0\bigg(\frac{1}{t_0^{1-\gamma}}+1\bigg)\le c_2t_0^\gamma$$
for all $t_0\in (0,1]$ for some $c, c_2>0$.